# I really don't understand this if with NOT! operator

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, arguments

firstly here is my code :

```
const removeFromArray = function (...args) {
const array = args[0];
const newArray = [];
array.forEach((item) => {
    if (!args.includes(item)) {
        newArray.push(item);
    }
});
return newArray;
```

The problem is this `!args.includes(item)`, the NOT operator, it really makes no sense in my mind in this case...  I tried to reformulate, rewrite but it doesn't help.

The function is supposed to push every element into the array unless it is included in the function arguments (for example with arguments like this : `removeFromArray([1, 2, 3], 2, 4)`) but how the 'unless' work with this if condition ?

Can you light up my lantern please ?

Comment: @Teemu _"and `!` converts the result to a boolean"_ - `.includes()` already returns a boolean. `!` negates the return value of `.includes()`

Comment: `if(!args.includes(item))` if we directly translate in more human speech "if not args includes item". And if we re-arrange it to sound less like Yoda, then it's "if args (does) not include item"

Comment: @Andereas Maybe I was a bit inaccurate, but It doesn't matter what the operand returns, `!` always returns a boolean.

Comment: @Teemu Your comment is still not correct. The result is not converted because there's nothing to convert.

Comment: Do you at least understand what [`args.includes(item)`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is?

Comment: You can change the definition to: `function (array, ...args)`. You can skip the `array = args[0]` declaration and `args.includes(item)` won't check against the array in the `0` index

Comment: Perhaps you should take some time to read [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-logical-not-operator). If you find that too technical, try the [user-friendly version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT).

Comment: @Andreas According to [the standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-logical-not-operator), internal ToBoolean method is always executed, though the method returns its argument when it already is a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you kind of interpreting the "unless" as literal here and I see how this might be a little bit confusing at first.

Perhaps if it was rephrased, it might be less confusing:
don't push element into array unless it's NOT including in the arguments.
Or more literal to actual code:
if item is NOT in the arguments, add it to the array

Comment: Oh thank you I FINALLY understand with your more literal version !

Answer (score 0):

`.includes()` returns `true` or `false` and `!` negates the result. The loop will only execute if `.includes()` in your example returns `false`.

To me it seems as if you want to filter the array, so maybe you should use the `.filter()` method:

`const newArray = array.filter((el)=>!(testArray.includes(el)))`